# java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed is thrown on Windows but works fine on Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run commands using Runtime.getRuntime.exec() in Java.

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process process = r.exec("telnet 172.16.221.87 "); 
InputStream is = process.getInputStream(); 
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream(); 
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
br.write("ditech\r\n");
br.flush(); // The exception is coming on last line that is br.flush();
```

When I run code in Linux, then its working fine. But when same code is run on Windows, it throws following error:

```
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.telnet.ConnectToTelnet.doTelnet(ConnectToTelnet.java:132)
        at com.telnet.ConnectToTelnet.main(ConnectToTelnet.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Comment: maybe a firewall issue

Comment: @ScaryWombat That would prevent a connection, not interrupt a running I/O operation. OP you will have to post some code.

Comment: Firewall is turned off.

Comment: 'Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = r.exec("telnet 172.16.221.87 ");
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
br.write("ditech\r\n");
br.flush();
'

The exception is coming on last line that is br.flush();

Comment: What's the command ?

Comment: @SurinderRajpal please update your question with your code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Please check code.

Comment: so what do you see if you `telnet 172.16.221.87 ` from your windows box (not java)

Comment: @SurinderRajpal Please don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that's it's totally illegible.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Output of telnet 172.16.221.87

Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service

login:

Comment: and then if you post `ditech\r\n` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat after that 
Password:

Comment: as expected eh?  Sorry

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes that is expected.

Comment: so what happens if you do not flush? I usually use a printWriter in this case.  Maybe you could a bit more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the process's output. It has almost certainly told you something that you've ignored by pressing ahead to the login phase. You need to either start two separate threads to read the `stdout` and `stderr,` or use the `Process` and `ProcessBuilder` classes, merge `stderr` and `stdout`, and use a single thread.

Have the thread just print the output for the moment. That will tell you exactly what the current problem is. More generally you should wait for the `login:` prompt before writing the username, wait for the `password:` prompt before writing the password, and so on for all the other things you're going to do in this Telnet session: and if you get anything unexpected you need to react accordingly.

Just blindly shovelling output at the processs is only going to lead to more puzzles like this one.

Comment: I'm waiting for the prompt and then providing username and same in the case of password. But didn't got the solution.